How can Mayday shoot webs without a web-shooter device?
Here is a picture of Mayday shooting webs without using
a web-shooter device:

How can Mayday shoot webs without a web-shooter device?

Yes, Mayday does have a web shooter.
In the trailer for Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse, Peter B. Parker mentions, while Mayday swings by:

"I knew I was gonna regret making her that web shooter."

Apparently Peter himself crafted the device for her, against his own better judgement. If you look closely, you can even spot it on her arm in the form of a cute flower bracelet.

However, in the scene you referenced, Mayday is shown shooting webs from her other arm, which is never explained. The most likely explanation for this would be an animation error, since the mechanical web shooter was already established in the trailer.
